# Keyboard overlaps input if input is "position:absolute"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making a chat app with ionic that has an ion-input at the bottom of the screen inside a div with the following CSS:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

The problem is that when running the app on certain android phones the keyboard overlaps the input and the user can't see what he is typing. In iOS is everything working fine.

If I remove the CSS above, everything works fine (the input stays on focus, at the middle of the screen).

The strangest part, is that if I create a new project and try to recreate the problem, i simply can't. Even with the CSS above everything works fine, in all devices. The problems seems to appear only in the specific project I'm working on, but i have no clue what might be causing this.

Comment: Are the projects using the same version of the ionic keyboard plugin? Maybe you changed the ionic config in `app.module` (look for `Ionic.forRoot()`).

Comment: yes, they are using the same version of the ionic keyboard plugin. What exactly should i look for in app.module.ts? I have the line IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp) in both projects.

Comment: It is possible to pass a config object to the IonicModule like that: `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { ... })`, I thought you may have done some settings like the ones suggested [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11501#issuecomment-299054124).